# How to remove non-ascii characters when reading csv file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read the following csv file https://storage.googleapis.com/play_public/supported_devices.csv using pandas:

```
dataframe = pandas.read_csv(DATA_FILE, sep=",", usecols=col_names, on_bad_lines='warn', encoding="UTF-16LE", encoding_errors='ignore', engine="python")
```

but some rows are decoded with "/u" characters, for example: "\u98db\u99ac (T500TLT)".
How can I remove these rows from the dataframe?

Comment: for col in dataframe.columns:
    dataframe[col] = dataframe[col].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore')

Comment: I have no problem with your file. Which lines do you see the unicode characters?

Comment: @Corralien in all the lines with Chinese characters. For example: lines 11265-11398

Comment: Where do you display your rows? You need an UTF-16 capable terminal. What I see [here](https://i.imgur.com/pHrRxGm.png)

Comment: @Corralien I go over the dataframe in a for loop and save the data in a json file. Then I open the json file and it shows these "/u" characters.